# Why do ATR aircraft have a dedicated power management selector for each engine?

Tags: aircraft-design, atr-72, atr-42

ATR aircraft have a split power management selector in order to allow both engines to be commanded seperately.

[image: An image showing what I mean]
 <sub>Source: [Magnar Nordal](https://youtu.be/behqG4Dw0Go&)</sub>

but what is the purpose of having this facility? do pilots ever move the selectors seperately?